# Segmentation fault in small C program

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a C program. It compiles fine but when I try to run the binary I get a seg fault. I ran gdb but I got a problem at the following line

```
*total = a;
```

The problem is right at the beginning of the code. Here it is:

```
main(){
  int a[] = {1,1,1,0,0,0,0};
  int **total; //array of int arrays
  *total = a; //i.e. set total's first array to be a.
```

I'm new to C and pointers. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`total` points to a pointer `p` which points to an int. By assigning to `*total`, you're assigning to `p`. But `total` hasn't been initialized, so you're assigning a value into a random location. You need to initialize `total` -- for example

```
int * p;
int** total = &p;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the segfault because `total` is uninitialized and so `*total` points to a random space in memory. You want to allocate space for total:

```
total = malloc(sizeof (int *) * NUM_ARRAYS);
```

Alternatively, you can ignore the pointers and make total an array:

```
int *total[NUM_ARRAYS];
```

Demote the arrays `total` points to to pointers to their first elements, and you're good to use it like this:

```
total[0] = a;
```

If you think of pointers as holding the addresses of variables, things might be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The code need not always give you a segmentation fault.  When you declare

```
     int *p
```

sizeof(int*) bits are allocated to p.(This is 32 in the case of a 32 bit compiler.) p is supposed to point to whatever is stored in the allocated space. Now as you haven't initialized this value. So this could contain some random value. When you do

```
    *p=10 //say
```

you are essentially trying to access the location. If the location comes outside the memory accessible to your process, you get a segmentation fault. If the location happens to be accessible, this will "corrupt" the location and your program behaves mysteriously.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated any memory to `total`. With `total` uninitialized, assigning to `*total` is invoking undefined behaviour. Luckily, you're getting a segfault. As long as you allocate memory to `total` (or just use an array of pointers, as I'm guessing that's your intent), it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`total` points to *something*. You haven't specified what it points to (which is supposed to be another pointer), and yet you're trying to write something to that location, hence the error.